# Serverless VPC Connector for Cloud Function cant access compute instance through private IP

Tags: gcp, google-cloud-functions

I have two GCP compute instances set within a VPC 'myVpc' of subnet range, sayy 50.24.0.0/20. On one of this instances I have a docker container running on the port 2376.
I want to be able to access this docker service using python on cloud function, and so I set up TLS configurations.
The main goal is to use python in cloud functions to access docker on this remote instance through its private IP. so I then set up a Serverless VPC  Connector that uses 'myVpc' and a subnet range of 50.24.16.0/28.

when I run this python script on the second compute instance where docker is not hosted, the code works and I am able to access the docker service deployed on the first instance, but but I cant access the docker service from cloud functions.

I'm guessing there is an issue with the way I set up the VPC connector? or my firewalls or something, I have tried to include ingress and egress rules to allow connection to and from the IP 50.24.0.0/28 on the docker port but it doesnt work.

I will appreciate any help please.